# mongodb geoSpatial query doesn't work

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-shell

I'm trying to fetch records within a specific radius in km/miles.

mongodb 2d index:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({locaction:"2d"})
```

a record in the collection has the indexed key:

```
"location" : { "longitude" : 34.791592164168, "latitude" : 32.0516908 0405 }
```

Calling collection's getIndexes() from shell gives me this:

```
       ...{
           "v" : 1,
           "key" : {
                   "location" : "2d"
           },
           "ns" : "events.events",
           "name" : "location_2d"
   }...
```

despite all the above, trying to fetch records with this command fails:

```
> db.events.find({location:{ $near :{ longitude:34,latitude:32},$maxDistance:10 / 3963.192}})
```

anyone can point out what prevent this from working?

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: Try giving an array value to your `$near` key: - `{$near: [34, 32]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, `$near` takes an array of the two target values, so you can try giving your values in array: -

```
db.events.find({location:{ $near : [34, 32],$maxDistance:10 / 3963.192}})
```